# ng2-translate: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(…) on bootstrap

Tags: angular, internationalization, systemjs, ng2-translate

I have the following error on bootstrap:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(…).

I'm on **Angular2 RC1** and using [`ng2-translate 2.1`](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate).

Also, the issue was still there while in previous versions: **Angular2 Beta-17** and `ng2-translate 1.11`.

Here is the `boot.ts`

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader, TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(TranslateLoader, {
        useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'i18n', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
    }), TranslateService]);
```

Here is the `systemjs.config.js`

```
  var  map = {
    ....
    'ng2-translate': 'docs/default/libs/ng2-translate'
  };
  var packages = {
    ...
    'ng2-translate': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
```

If I have breakpoint in `boot.js`, in the setter for `ng2_translate`:

```
function (ng2_translate_1_1) {
    ng2_translate_1 = ng2_translate_1_1;
},
```

`ng2_translate_1_1` is "almost" empty:

```
JSON.stringify(ng2_translate_1_1)
=> "{"default":{}}"
```

Comment: Perhaps it is not reasonable trying to fix beta-17, since latest RC versions have i18n support builtin.

Comment: This is actually related to **Angular RC1**. I haven't found any recent documentation about Angular 2 **i18n**. Please point me to anything. Even the official i18n is not available.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution:**

I am at **RC1** with **angular-cli**, had same problem and managed to get translate work. These are code parts that might be useful to locate your problems.

System config: *(notice `format: 'cjs'` at packages config, without this option TranslateService was undefined )*

```
System.config({
    map: {
        /* ... */
        'ng2-translate': 'vendor/ng2-translate',
        /* ... */
    },
    packages: {
        /* ... */
        'ng2-translate': {
            format: 'cjs',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: 'ng2-translate'
        },
        /* ... */
    }
})
```

To vendor folder i am copying as `'ng2-translate/**/*.js'` so `'ng2-translate/ng2-translate.js'` and also `'ng2-translate/src/*.js'` are copied

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help